# check a condition and perform an operation on each element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

```
q = np.arange(0,mt.pi,0.01)
q = q.tolist()
def qprime(q,qc):
    for x in q:
        if x < qc:
            a = cmt.sqrt(x**2-qc**2)
            return a.real
        else:
            return cmt.sqrt(x**2-qc**2)

qp = qprime(q, 0.8509)
```

I am trying to create a list called "qp".  This list needs to be created by taking a previous list, "q", squaring each element in "q", subtracting a scalar, "qc", from each element in "q", and finally square rooting each element.  Obviously, some elements in this list may return a complex number.  If this happens, I only want the real part.  I am not sure what my code is doing, but it is only returning a single value for qp, 0.0.

Any advice?

Comment: The `return` statement exits the function. You should append the results to a `list` (for example) and `return` the `list` once the loop ends.

Comment: You code seems to exit after processing the first element from the list. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to compute whether or not there will be an imaginary part.  Just return the real part of the number regardless.

```
from cmath import sqrt
from math import pi as PI

def qprime(x, qc):
    return sqrt(x**2 - qc**2).real

qp = [qprime(x, 0.8509) for x in np.arange(0, PI, 0.01)]
```

Comment: oh, I didn't realize I could call a function in a list comprehension.  That makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you pass an array and I guess you want this:

```
q = np.arange(0,mt.pi,0.01)
q = q.tolist()
def qprime(q,qc):
    for x in q:
        if x < qc:
            a = cmt.sqrt(x**2-qc**2)
            yield a.real
        else:
            yield cmt.sqrt(x**2-qc**2)

qp = [v for v in qprime(q, 0.8509)]
```

Comment: compute `cmt.sqrt(x**2-qc**2)` out of the loop to avoid copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement exits the function. You should append the results to a `list` or `np.array` and `return` once the loop ends.

```
q = np.arange(0, mt.pi, 0.01)
q = q.tolist()

def qprime(q, qc):
    result = np.array([]) # initialize array 
    for x in q:
        if x < qc:
            a = cmt.sqrt(x**2-qc**2)
            result = np.append(result, a.real)
        else:
            result = np.append(result, cmt.sqrt(x**2-qc**2))

    return result

qp = qprime(q, 0.8509)
```

Or you can get the same result with a `list` comprehension, removing the loop inside the function since it's pointless :

```
q = np.arange(0, mt.pi, 0.01)
q = q.tolist()

def qprime(q, qc):
    if q < qc: # no need for a loop
        a = cmt.sqrt(q**2-qc**2)
        return a.real
    else:
        return cmt.sqrt(q**2-qc**2)

qp = np.array([qprime(i, 0.8509) for i in q])
```

Comment: Oh, the I didn't realize I the return statement exits the function.  Makes perfect sense.  Thanks!